# Java - Recursive Sum of a Triangle

Tags: java, recursion

I am trying to compute the sum of a triangle in an array where you add the max value of the three numbers below it (directly below, below and one to the left, and below and one to the right).  I believe my problem is in where/how I am getting the number of rows in each triangle (numRows), due to the fact that it never updates past 3.  I am not sure what I should do differently to get this to update as I thought it should update whenever the recursive method is called and is incremented down by 1 each time, but that is apparently not the case.  Below is my code.  Thank you all in advance!

```
/**
*
* @author Ra'kiir
*/
public class RecursiveTriangleSum {

public static int globalRows = 0;


/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 * @throws java.io.FileNotFoundException
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

    int[][] tempArray = new int[][]{
    {4}, //number of test cases
    {3}, //start: test case 1
    {1},
    {1, 2},
    {1, 2, 3},
    {5}, //start: test case 2
    {1},
    {1, 3},
    {3, 2, 1},
    {2, 1, 3, 4},
    {3, 5, 2, 4, 1},
    {1}, //start: test case 3
    {3},
    {6}, //start: test case 4
    {1},
    {2, 1},
    {1, 2, 3},
    {4, 3, 2, 1},
    {1, 2, 3, 4, 5},
    {3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3}
    };

    int numTestCases = tempArray[0][0];
    globalRows++;  
    for (int z=0; z<numTestCases; z++) {

        int sum = recursiveTriSum(tempArray, globalRows, 0);
        System.out.println("The Sum is:  " + sum);
    }
} //End main method

public static int recursiveTriSum(int[][] array, int i, int j) { //i=row, j=column
//        System.out.println("Recursion Runs");

    int numRows = array[globalRows][0];
    if (i>numRows) {
//            System.out.println("IF");

        return 0;
    }
    else {
//            System.out.println("Else");
        int t1 = recursiveTriSum(array, i+1, j);
        int t2 = recursiveTriSum(array, i+1, j+1);
        int t3 = recursiveTriSum(array, i+1, j-1);

        int p1 = Math.max(t1, t2);
        int p2 = array[i][j] + Math.max(p1, t3);

        globalRows++;
        numRows--;
        return p2; 
    }

} //End recursiveTriSum method
} //End of Main Class
```

Comment: What would the answer be for a couple of the test cases?

Comment: @Marichyasana The answers for the 4 test cases are as follows:

Test Case #1:  6
Test Case #2:  14
Test Case #3:  3
Test Case #4:  16

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over each triangle as:
- Get first row of triangle, initialize variable say sum = first element and another variable say index = 0.
- Move to next line in triangle, start from index and pick up next two elements. If fist element is greater second, do not increment variable i.e. index otherwise increment it and add the greater value to sum.
e.g.

```
If(array[index] > array[index+1])
       sum += array[index];
     else{
         sum += array[index+1];
         index++;
       }
```

and so on till last row of triangle.